# Getting OnPremisesDistinguishedName attribute via MicrosoftGraphAPI

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My requirement is to fetch the **OnPremisesDistinguishedName** attribute of a user object via Microsoft Graph API.

After doing some extensive R & D I have observed that in the blog post
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/df2b1b2b-a7ca-4b34-9ddf-82ffd78fc96e/how-to-retrive-ou-details-in-scripts-that-are-synced-with-office-365-with-aadc?forum=onlineservicesexchange
the same can be achieved via the powershell module as

```
Get-AzureADUser -SearchString <any string> | select -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty)["onPremisesDistinguishedName"]
```

However how can this be achieved via GraphAPI ?
Any thoughts?

Comment: The only workaround at this point of time is to use the AADGraphAPI. Using the endpoint https://graph.windows.net/<TENANT-ID>/users?api-version=1.6 the AADGraphAPI returns a quite big list of attributes for each user object which includes the OnPremisesDistinguishedName attribute as well. It is quite sad that GraphAPI doesnt provide this attribute even with their beta endpoint.

Comment: Thanks to @mrgoos for the update regarding the availability of OnPremisesDistinguishedName attribute via the MicrosoftGraphAPI now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPremisesDistinguishedName` exist from [January 2019](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blame/38daf7aaf45070f7aba19bc1654f9772085613fc/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user.md#L101).

[API DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: One thing to add  is that it is only populated when you explicitly select it (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 3):

Graph API doesn't provide the onPremisesDistinguishedName property.
Currently, we can get the following properties related to onPremises: onPremisesDomainName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes,onPremisesImmutableId   onPremisesLastSyncDateTime,onPremisesProvisioningErrors,onPremisesSamAccountName
onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesSyncEnabled,onPremisesUserPrincipalName

Call the graph api like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test@test.onmicrosoft.com/?$select=onPremisesDomainName,onPremisesDistinguishedName
```

Because no property named **onPremisesDistinguishedName**, so although we add it to the query but it will be ignore.

If the above properties doesn't suit your requirement, you can submit an feature request in the [user vocie](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

More information for your reference: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user

Comment: Yes it sad that MicrosoftGraphAPI doesnt provide this simple feature even with their beta end point. When Microsoft itself reiterates to switch over to GraphAPI from the AADGraphAPI am forced to provide an implementation to use the AADGraphAPI just to get the value of this attribute  onPremisesDistinguishedName as this attribute is business critical for me. I will be submitting a feature request shortly.

Comment: Thanks Seiya, your input helped me.